# can't access localhost via android device using Easyphp

Tags: android, xampp, localhost, wamp, easyphp

I'm using **Easyphp** to host my local website on windows and It works flawlessly. Now I'm trying to launch the website from my android phone. But It doesn't seem to work by just typing :

> http://pclocalip:8080 
>   or 
>   http://pclocalip

As other web hosts like **XAMPP** and **WAMP** allow it by just doing that.

Comment: are you using default android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default android emulator

The first step is to start the AVD with an increased partition size otherwise you may get an out of memory error when you try to save the modified hosts file

> emulator -avd MyAVD -partition-size 128

You then have to remount the system partition so that it is writeable

> adb remount

Then copy the hosts file from the emulated device to the host machine

> adb pull /etc/hosts

Edit the hosts file so that it includes mappings for all relevant virtual host names

> 127.0.0.1        localhost
>
> 10.0.2.2         pclocalip

Then copy the updated file back to the emulated device

> adb push hosts /etc/hosts

You should then be able to visit http://pclocalip in the emulator’s browser and see the correct site

PS: Note that `10.0.2.2` here is the localhost IP address of your machine that run the AVD

Comment: Thanks for the help @Hendra, although I just switched to **XAMPP** and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module especially for that : [www.easyphp.org/documentation/devserver/mobile-for-devserver.php](https://www.easyphp.org/documentation/devserver/mobile-for-devserver.php)

"With the module "Mobile", you can test your code on your mobile phone / tablet and see if your website / application is mobile friendly."